# How does Entity Framework Core work with foreach()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework Core and I was thinking, if I have an id list, and I want to find each of these ids in a database, the easiest way to do this would be with something like

```
foreach(var id in idList)
{
    testList.Add(context.myTable.FindAsync(id).Result);
}
```

But, is this really a good idea? I'm assuming this would make a connection to the database for each one of the ids in the idList, and if I have 800000 ids in the list or something absurd like that it would destroy my performance, right? Could someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: That's a very bad idea, executing 800000 separate queries. On the other hand, requesting 800K rows by ID is a bad idea in general. Databases aren't file systems, they're built to accelerate set based queries. A query returning the 800K rows created in the last year will be faster than one specifying 800K IDs

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X, (perhaps a very complex or slow query? a flat file with IDs to process?), and assume Y is the solution (use an ORM like EF and ask for each row by ID). When that doesn't work, you ask about Y, not X. What is the actual problem you want to solve? Perhaps you can solve it by improving your query? Or importing the data into a staging table?

Comment: One thing is certain - ORMs are unsuitable for ETL jobs. Pulling 800K rows to the client and sending them back will be 800K times slower than a proper SQL query running on the server. With ETL there are no objects or behavior, just data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
var items = await context.myTable.Where(idList.Contains(id)).ToListAsync();
testList.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: The query should be on a separate list and awaited. This isn't only for improved readabvility, `ToListAsync()` executes the query and can throw for any number of reasons. A one-liner not only hides what's going on, it makes error handling and debugging harder.

Comment: BTW `Contains` can only accept ~1000 items at a time

Comment: @FernandoAraujo foreach doesn't affect EF Core. Your original code executes `FindAsync` 800K times. What are you trying to do though? Why specify 800K IDs? That's not how databases work

Comment: @FernandoAraujo, it's depends on how you manage the dbContext, but the foreach will make a X queries to the database instead of doing one query using the `Where`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm just wondering what the best way of finding a large amount of result from a list is

Comment: @FernandoAraujo do it on the server, not the client. ORMs are meant to work with object graphs for specific use cases, not process 800K rows. That's what ETL tools are for. What are you trying to do? Why not write an UPDATE query to do what you want on the server?

Comment: @FernandoAraujo a server has far more cores, far more RAM and far faster disks than any client - never mind the network latency and limited bandwidth between client and server.

Comment: I wouldn't use List<T> but HashSet<T> when doing this kind of logic. He mentioned that there will probably be around 800k items in the list so a List<T>.Contains won't be nearly as performant as HashSet<T>.Contains would. When using HashSet<T>.Contains it will also probably make more sense not to use async/await since the overhead of using it will slow down performance because the execution time of the lambda expression would be extremely fast..